# How expensive is the db.get() method in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Imagine I have multiple collections naming Employee and Product.

I need to insert and query these collections frequently

So usually I do, (node.js)

```js
var employee = db.get('employee')
employee.find({},function(err,docs){ blah. blah.. });
```

ie., use db.get before every query or insert statements. Is it the correct way, or should i maintain some global or instance variable that is initialized to db.get('employee') and use that variable every now and then.

Is db.get() expensive or negligible? Which approach is better?

Comment: comparing to eployee.find() *get()* doesn't comsume any resource, it just sets a pointer to collection.

Comment: Considering the fact that, db is in a seperate machine, is getting a pointer for every operation a correct way of doing it?

Comment: if I am not wrong it just tells (before your query) that you want to work with this collection and that's it. It is ok to leave it as you have.